# chroot failed to run command

Tags: chroot

Now after 2 days of pulling my hair it is obvious for me that on other ubuntu machine I can chroot into a VM client (VBOX).

I am trying to chroot from live media to a ubuntu VM client.
I mounted:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys

chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

> chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': no such file or directory

[image: this image is no longer relevant]

I check /bin/bash and *bash is there

[image]

Below is an example with chroot on other machines with any live distros to any client (linux-based only).

[image]

Did I miss something? Did I missed any libs on first machine?
I chrooted with ubuntu live and every time worked flawlessly. Thanks, guys!

Update: Finally works, some libs were missing.

[image: Solved]

Comment: What is the meaning of `/dev/sda1 /mnt`, shouldn't it be `mount /dev/sda /mnt`? Your recent mountpoint is not `/mnt` but `/mnt/sda1` as indicated in the screenshot, so it looks as if you didn't setup your chroot correctly.

Comment: thanks, mook765, typo when I posted, corrected now. No, should not be sda (block device) should be sda1 (partition). Why lsblk shows /mnt/sda1 I do not know yet.

Comment: once try chroot /mnt  (dont use /bin/bash after that).

Comment: I did that before, same error

Comment: ok then try this, mount -o bind /lib /mnt/lib and mount -o bind /lib64 /mnt/lib64

Comment: this is what I was thinking once to create fresh jail. I will try that and let you guys know

Comment: now it is complaining about libtermcap.so.2. ldd /bin/bash does not ask for that. I do not understand how can work on other machine (same ubuntu)